# dotnet publish not generating correct assemblies on Ubuntu Server

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, command-line-interface

I am struggling a bit on publish dotnet core project on server from last 7 days. Previously, it was working fine when all of sudden, it stopped working. Below is the cli I use:

```
dotnet publish -c release -o <directory>
```

When publishing, there is no error, but when I run generated dll by dotnet projectname.dll.

It gives files assemblies are mismatching:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

This and many of files from this namespace are creating problem, do what I am doing is publishing at my local system and then copy paste these files.

I tried lot of solutions from different sources but none of them have worked for me, below is one of them:

```
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/987
```

My csproj contents are like this:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-Jwt-9EB56A08-EA05FF-4EEF-B339-DEE0A5CA1545</UserSecretsId>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.3</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>  
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Myproj\**" />
    <Compile Remove="publish\**" />
    <Compile Remove="wwwrootold\**" />
    <Content Remove="Myproj\**" />
    <Content Remove="publish\**" />
    <Content Remove="wwwrootold\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Myproj\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="publish\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="wwwrootold\**" />
    <None Remove="Myproj\**" />
    <None Remove="publish\**" />
    <None Remove="wwwrootold\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BlockchainAPI" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Cryptography.ECDSA.Secp256k1" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="HBitcoin" Version="0.1.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy" Version="0.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.Core" Version="7.0.4-IR-191" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NBitcoin.Litecoin" Version="1.0.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="NBitcoin.Zcash" Version="1.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="secp256k1_vc120" Version="0.1.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="stellar-dotnetcore-sdk" Version="1.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProj.core\MyProj.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProj.Data\MyProj.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: please show your `.csproj` file

Comment: @Set, did you get the solution?